# Time Variable/Function not updating in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

(I'm using jQuery, bootstrap & bootbox because JSFiddle doesn't show a console.log)

So I'm trying to console.log the current second but it's just logging what second the page loaded at. I changed it from a variable to a function to see if that would help but it still does the same thing.

[JSFiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/k60t5kxa/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var d = new Date();
    // I changed this from a variable that was just
    // var secs = d.getSeconds();
    // Thinking that it was saving the second in which it loaded
    // As the second, but that still didn't help.
    var secs = function () {
        return d.getSeconds();
    };
    setInterval(function(){
        // This bootbox.alert is like a fancy console.log
        bootbox.alert(secs().toString());
        // Change the 100000 to 1000 when you want to run the code, and change it again when you want to edit it as It'll keep spamming you.
    }, 100000);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `new Date()` every time you want the seconds to update.

Change your secs function to the following and remove the d variable.

```
var secs = function () {
    return new Date().getSeconds();
};
```

This change will look up the current time every time you call `secs();`

Your implementation was referencing the same point in time `variable d` which is why the seconds didn't seem to change.

[See my update to your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k60t5kxa/3/)